# BlueStacks 2 WIFI MAC Address

Tags: wi-fi, android-emulator, bluestacks, mac-address

How do I change BlueStacks 2 WIFI MAC Address to a specific WIFI MAC Address. For example I want to specifically change it to 11:22:33:44:55:66?

Comment: I guess you'd have to root it first. BTW, why do u want to do that? Maybe for using same WhatsApp number on PC & phone?